# CLI Has stopped working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am getting a strange error which I am not sure if Laravel related.  I have created a generic Document Model to store data for different types of Documents.  It works perfectly for everything apart from one document.  One of my documents have a load of checkboxes which take the following form

```
<div class="col-md-6 checkbox checkbox-danger">
    {!! Form::checkbox('testingOptions[]', 'Style vs. product based', null, ['class' => 'styled', 'id' => 'checkbox1']) !!}
    <label for="checkbox1">
        Style vs. product based
    </label>
</div>
```

So the selected options are stored in testingOptions[].  In my controller, if I output the inputted data I get something like this

```
array:10 [▼
  "_token" => "XGz0x2nivwEuHmYziosFzExGjwWY41GZDdUxSaJi"
  "description" => ""
  "objective" => "sfrgdf"
  "audience" => "gdfgd"
  "segmentation" => ""
  "testingOptions" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "Style vs. product based"
    1 => "Use contest or prize draw"

  ]
  "successMeasure" => ""
  "deliverables" => ""
  "keyDates" => ""
  "filePath" => array:1 [▶]
]
```

Now because testingOptions is an array, I need to treat it differently when saving.  My generic safe code is like so

```
$inputs = $request->all();

foreach ($inputs as $key => $value) {
    if($key !== '_token' && $key !== 'filePath' && $key !== '_method' && $key !== 'testingOptions') {
        $documentData = new DocumentData();
        $documentData->documentId = $document->id;
        $documentData->key = $key;
        $documentData->value = $value;
        $documentData->save();
    }
}
```

With the above, if I try to safe the Document, I get an Windows error saying CLI has stopped working, and this stops my php server.  The issue comes down to the if statement above, more specifically checking for testingOptions.  If I remove this part from the if statement, I do not get the CLI error.

Has anyone seen something like this before?

Thanks